# how do I actually run Flash CS5 using wine(or virtualbox)?

Tags: wine, virtualbox

I installed wine. never used it for anything. I already use flash on my other os(win 7) but don't know how to open it from ubuntu using wine. Lots of tutorial about installing wine/virtualbox but none specifically for launching flash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that there is a Flash plugin for Firefox and also Chrome?  Will this do what you want?

Comment: Looks like he want's to run the Adobe application to create Flash things (Animations, scripts, applications,whatever), called Adobe Flash Professional, not the plugin used to view (or run) those apps.

Answer (score 0):

The Wine App database has good information on how to set these things up just go to the page linked and look through the listing and comments below to see if there are problems/workarounds.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21127

Also, you might try to check if it is supported under PlayOnLinux (a program which will try to implement workarounds automatically) by seeing if it is under one of the categories in this page:

http://www.playonlinux.com/repository/

Hope I could help.